# The Verb for Polymorphism

Tags: terminology, solid-state-chemistry

How can you elegantly describe that a polymorphic substance changes its structure?

> - It polymorphs
> - It morphs
> - It undergoes polymorphic transition
> - It experiences a morphic change

Or what would be even better terms?

Comment: Chemical ELL.SE! Please propose! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It "transitions from one polymorph to another"

It "transitions to another polymorph"

It "transition to polymorph beta"

It "transforms to another polymorph"

It "transforms to polymorph beta"

I like "transitions" better than "transforms", but I've seen both

Comment: I see "transition" as the more common form

Comment: Does "polymorph" have a different definition in chemistry than colloquial English?  Because here you're using polymorph as a form/shape rather than as an object that changes shape.  A thing doesn't change _to_ a polymorph, a polymorph changes shape to a thing.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(materials_science) doesn't seem to disagree with me, though my knowledge of chemistry is minimal so I may be dead wrong here.

Comment: This is what puzzled me in the beginning and is the reason why I ask. Originally, a polymorph is a substance which can have different shapes at the same conditions. But apperently each form of this polymorph is called "polymorph". Ugh...

Comment: In chemistry, the different polymorphs have different arrangements of atoms or molecules, but there is no macroscopic change in the shape of an object.

Comment: @DavePhD I would like to object that there were never a macroscopic change of the crystal.  If atoms and molecules rearrange to yield a new polymorph with a unit cell of different volume, the density of the sample will change.  If these changes exceed the Young moduli, the crystal may become brittle and shatter into pieces.